# Dismiss AlertViewController when we tap on out side of the AlertView Controller iOS8 (iPad)

Tags: ipad, ios8, uialertcontroller

I am using UIAlertControllerStyleAlert with the UIAlertController. Its working fine. But I cant able to dismiss it when I touch/tap out side the UIAlertController. Please help me on this. I am using following code:

```
            UIAlertAction *actionDelete = nil;
            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Testing message"
                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            actionDelete = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"YES", nil) style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
               // delete action
            }];

            [alertController addAction:actionDelete];
            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```